# UI mocking framework - that allows for dragging and dropping widgets + html generation

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

I am looking for a front end UI mocking framework that allows:

1. Dragging and dropping widgets on to a "palette". Resizing them,
   custom defining css styles on the widget, and generates an HTML in
   the background which can then be "re-used" for making the real
   product
2. Double clicking on the button in the palette yields a JS based
       "click handler" that can then be used to add basic JS code (I don't
       care if all of this is done as a part of a single HTML file)

I don't mind if its a paid software. 
The idea is to be able to make the mocks that reflect the real product as closely as possible and being able to reuse css/html from the mocks done.
This also saves time not investing in doing layout work in html.

I've definitely seen such proprietary software built inside large firms, but wondering if there's an off the shelf product available